# Is the r effect size that is used with Wilcoxon sing rank test also good to use with sign test

Tags: r, effect-size, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Is the r effect size that is used with Wilcoxon sing rank test (more about it here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_appropriate_effect_size_calculation_for_Wilcoxon_signed_rank_test_related_samples ) is also good to use with Sign Test (more about it here: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/sign-test-using-spss-statistics.php)?

Comment: Please edit your question so that if any of the links disappeared, the question would still be readily understood. You can retain the links for context, but the question should still work without them. [I'd also warn against relying too heavily on random websites that purport to explain/teach statistics. Many are written by people with no training in statistics outside their own application area, typically from other people in the same boat, and in many cases the ratio of errors to correct statements is disturbingly high.]

Comment: I'd like to add a comment about the Research Gate link, and my answer below, here.  For the paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test, it is common to divide the *z* statistic by the square root of the number pairs and report that as an effect size statistic, *r*.  I have found though, that that statistic can't reach -1 or 1 unless there are ties in the paired differences.  Instead I recommend the "paired-samples rank biserial correlation coefficient", which is often abbreviated rc.  This seems to have better properties.  Calc: King Rosopa Minium Statistical Reasoning in the Behavioral Sciences, 6th

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll call the effect size statistic mentioned *Wilcoxon paired r*, which is the *z* value divided by the square root of the number of pairs of observations.  (Although there is some dispute about what should be in the denominator in the referenced thread.)

The sign test assesses data in a way that isn't really compatible with the Wilcoxon signed rank test.  I might ask, *if you were interested in that kind of effect measurement, why are using the sign test instead of the signed-rank test?*

The sign test is basically looking at the paired values and counting those observations in sample A where the value is higher than that in sample B.  So, a reasonable effect size would be this proportion.  Jacob Cohen, 1988, *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*, suggests the effect size statistic we might call Cohen's *g*, which is simply the absolute value of this probability minus 0.50. You might also use the odds ratio, which is e.g. (A > B) / (B > A).

Comment: The reason why I want to use "sign test" instead of "Wilcoxon signed rank test" is that my data has not symmetric distribution of the differences between the two related groups. More on that assumption here: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-using-spss-statistics.php

Comment: I have no problem with using the sign test.  One thing that's nice about it is that it's easy to explain to an audience what it's testing for.  My suggestion is that the chosen effect size statistic should match the statistical test. ...  But also, I don't think that link has the assumptions of the test correct.

Comment: Can we use median difference produced by "Two-sample sign test with BSDA package" that is described here?  https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_07.html

Comment: Yes, reporting the difference in medians as an effect size makes perfect sense.

Comment: The Wilcoxon sign rank compares average ranks, not medians. You may use the Wilcoxon sign rank also for non-symmetrical data. when the data is symmetrical it is similar to comparing medians.